# flipclock countdown to specific date in specific timezone without reset

Tags: javascript, datetime, countdowntimer, flipclock

I am trying to create countdown to a specific date using flipclock without the timer resetting or people in different time-zones seeing different numbers. For example, I want to countdown to Feb 20, 12:00am MST.

My problem is that the clock resets when the browser is refreshed after it reaches 0, the time shows negative numbers. If people viewing this clock with the current configuration, it is counting down to Feb 20, 12am in *their* timezone.

I've started with the countdown to New Years compiled clock and set my date, but not sure how else to address the timezone and reset issues.

```
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Grab the current date
    var currentDate = new Date();

    // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
    var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 0, 1, 20, 0, 0);

    // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
    var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

    // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true,
        showSeconds: false,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Grab the current date
  var now = new Date();
  var currentDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
  currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 7);

  // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
  var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 0, 1, 20, 0, 0);

  // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
  var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

  // Limit time difference to zero
  if (diff < 0) {
    diff = 0;
  }

  // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    showSeconds: false,
    callbacks: {
      stop: function() {
        $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Part solving timezone issue (a bit ugly):

```
// Grab the current date
var now = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() - 7);
```

Part limiting time difference to not less than zero:

```
// Limit time difference to zero
if (diff < 0) {
  diff = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this in detail, I've manipulated this with different dates and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since the time you'd like to count down to is a specific time in a specific time zone, then the easiest way is to [pre-convert that time to UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html), and count down to that instead.

On Feb 20th 2016, US Mountain Time is at UTC-7, therefore:

```
2016-02-20 00:00:00 MST == 2016-02-20 07:00:00 UTC
```

So,

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var futureDate = Date.UTC(currentDate.getUTCFullYear(), 1, 20, 7, 0, 0);
var diff = (futureDate - currentDate.getTime()) / 1000;
```

I'll let someone else answer WRT the specifics of FlipClock and your reset issue - though you might consider asking it in a separate question.  (Try to ask only one question at a time in the future.)